# CollectionView memory VM:CoreAnimation memory allocated and abandoned

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a some  collectionViews and one table view that are in the same view controller. The rather strange problem is that when i scroll up-down I alway get memory increases. 
Instruments show a lot of allocation of VM:CoreAnimation objects but I can't track them down (they are inside collectionView itself).
prepare for reuse is getting called inside the cells, I checked this.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.receivedChannels = NO;
    self.ItemsDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    self.crtBatchSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];


    if ([[PSDeviceInfo sharedInstance] is_iPad]) {
        self.epgWidth = EPG_WIDTH_IPAD;
    } else {
        self.epgWidth = EPG_WIDTH_IPHONE;
    }
    crtBatchSetSize = 0;
    self.currentSelecteIndexOfDateCell = 0;
    //size
    self.widthDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    self.centerXDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    self.layout = [[MultipleLineLayout alloc] initWithWidthDictionary:self.widthDictionary andCenterXDictionary:self.centerXDictionary];
    self.ItemsCollectionVIew.collectionViewLayout = self.layout;
    self.ItemsCollectionVIew.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.ItemsCollectionVIew.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    [self.ItemsCollectionVIew registerClass:[ItemColectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemColectionCellID"];
    [self.hoursCollectionView registerClass:[HoursCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HoursColectionCellID"];
    [self.datePickerCollectionView registerClass:[DatePickerCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DatePickerColectionCellID"];


 }

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView == self.ItemsCollectionVIew){
        self.channelsTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.ItemsCollectionVIew.contentOffset.y);
        self.hoursCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.ItemsCollectionVIew.contentOffset.x, 0);
    }
    if (scrollView == self.channelsTableView) {
        self.ItemsCollectionVIew.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.ItemsCollectionVIew.contentOffset.x,self.channelsTableView.contentOffset.y);
    }
    if (scrollView == self.hoursCollectionView) {
        self.ItemsCollectionVIew.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.hoursCollectionView.contentOffset.x,self.ItemsCollectionVIew.contentOffset.y);
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *channelCellID = @"ChannelTableCellID";
    ChannelTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:channelCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myIndexInTable = indexPath.row;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell getData];
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.ItemsCollectionVIew reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    if (collectionView == self.datePickerCollectionView || collectionView == self.hoursCollectionView) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        if (self.receivedChannels) {
            return totalNoChannels;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (collectionView == self.datePickerCollectionView) {
        return DELTA_DAYS + 1;
    }else if (collectionView == self.hoursCollectionView) {
        return 48; //24 hours  *  2
    }else{
//        if (collectionView == self.ItemsCollectionVIew){
        NSArray *sectionItems = self.ItemsDict[@(section)];
        if (sectionItems) {
           // return sectionItems.count;
            return 100;
        } else {
            return 100;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (collectionView == self.datePickerCollectionView) {
        static NSString *ItemCellID = @"DatePickerColectionCellID";
        DatePickerCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self setDayAndDateforCell:cell at:indexPath];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[self getColorForCell:self.currentSelecteIndexOfDateCell == indexPath.row ? YES:NO]];
        return cell;
    }else if (collectionView == self.hoursCollectionView){
        static NSString *ItemCellID = @"HoursColectionCellID";
        HoursCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.hourLabel.text = [self getTimeLineCellValuerFor:indexPath];
        return cell;
    } else{
//    if (collectionView == self.datePickerCollectionView) {
        static NSString *ItemCellID = @"ItemColectionCellID";
        ItemColectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSArray *Items = self.ItemsDict[@(indexPath.section)];
        if (indexPath.row >= Items.count) {
            return cell;
        }
        MvpItem *prog = Items[indexPath.row];

        [cell updateInfo:prog];

        [cell setBackgroundColor:[self getColorForCell:NO]];

        return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate Methods
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (collectionView == self.datePickerCollectionView) {
        self.currentSelecteIndexOfDateCell = indexPath.row;
    }
    if (collectionView == self.ItemsCollectionVIew) {
        [self pushDetailsatIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

The code for the tableView cell is:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)prepareForReuse{
    self.thumbnailImage.image = nil;
    self.channel = nil;
    [self clearDelegate];
    [super prepareForReuse];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self clearDelegate];
}

- (void)clearDelegate
{
    NSString *url = self.channel.media_content.thumbPoster.url;
  //  [[ImageManager sharedInstance] removeDelegate:self forImgUrl:url];
    [[TVManager sharedInstance] removeDelegate:self];
}

- (void)getData
{
    [[TVManager sharedInstance] getChannelAndItemssForIndex:self.myIndexInTable forDateDelta:0 forDelegate:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveTotalNoChn:(NSInteger)totalChnNo{
    return;
}

- (void)didReceiveChannel:(MvpChannel *)channel withItemss:(NSArray *)Itemss forDateDelta:(NSInteger)date withIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    if (index != self.myIndexInTable) {
        return;
    }
    if ([self.channel isEqual:channel]) {
        return;
    }
    self.channel = channel;
    NSString *imgUrl = self.channel.media_content.thumbPoster.url;
//    UIImage *img = [[ImageManager sharedInstance] getImageForUrl:imgUrl forIndex:self.myIndexInTable withDelegate:self];
//    if (img) {
//        self.thumbnailImage.image = img;
//    }
}

#pragma mark - Image Delegate

- (void)didReceiveImage:(UIImage *)image forIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (index != self.myIndexInTable) {
        return;
    }
    if (image) {
        self.thumbnailImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.thumbnailImage.image = image;
        [self setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

And inside the collectionViewCell:

```
@interface ItemColectionCell ()

@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *genreLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *intervalLabel;

@end

@implementation ItemColectionCell //collection

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];

        self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.genreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.intervalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        [self.titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.genreLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.intervalLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [self.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.genreLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.intervalLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@“cf-Bold" size:15]];;
        [self.genreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@“cf-Regular" size:11]];;
        [self.intervalLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@“cf-Regular" size:11]];;

    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (void)prepareForReuse{
    self.titleLabel.text = nil;
    self.genreLabel.text = nil;
    self.intervalLabel.text = nil;
    [self.titleLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [self.genreLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [self.intervalLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [super prepareForReuse];
}

- (void)updateInfo:(MvpItem*)item{
    if (!item) {
        return;
    }

    NSDateFormatter *startTimeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [startTimeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];

    NSDateFormatter *endTimeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [endTimeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    NSString *startTime = [startTimeFormat stringFromDate:item.startTime];
    NSString *endTime = [endTimeFormat stringFromDate:item.endTime];

    self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7, self.frame.size.width - 10, 15);
    self.genreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, self.frame.size.width - 10, 15);
    self.intervalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 32, self.frame.size.width - 10, 15);

    self.titleLabel.text = item.title;
    self.genreLabel.text = @“tewst”;
    self.intervalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", startTime, endTime];

    [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    [self addSubview:self.genreLabel];
    [self addSubview:self.intervalLabel];
}
```

What ca I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the app on a device? Memory management is handled differently on the Simulator and can often times be misleading with respect to usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to remove the cell or heavy tasks triggered by displaying that cell when it did end displaying?

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```